# Git Hub Workflow (Errors pushing after setting upsteam)

Tags: git, github, ssh

So Currently I have knowledge that there is a completely predictable and functional work flow I can perform to place a folder on my computer on to the GitHub cloud.

What I do in order to perform this fear is make an empty repo on github with the same name as my local folder, clone that repo, then copy and paste everything in my local folder onto the local cloned repo. I then commit and push.

All goes well when I do this.

However, when I follow instructions on some tutorial websites, I am told to use a different method - I make an empty repo on Github, but I don't clone it and copy-paste the local files. Instead, I set the upstream. This seems to me like it would be quite a lot easier and I wish I were able to achieve this functionality.

I type the command `git remote add origin git@github.com:your_github_username/your_repository_name.git`

after `add`ing and `commit`ing but when I try and `push` I get this error: `

ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-maxpleaner: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
` .

I have poked around at similar problems described on Stack Overflow but I'm not understanding proposed solutions. Clearly, this isn't a dire situation of peril and torment but I hope I can learn to address seemingly trivial problems like this so that I can be a better computer programmer.

I sincerely appreciate your assistance and time.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the actual URL of the remote to be the `github-maxpleaner`, and your DNS isn't resolving that correctly. It needs to be `github.com/username/repository` instead for the network to know where to upload to.

To fix it and set the remote:

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:username/repository.git
```

Once you've set the upstream remote repository, you can just use `git push upstream --all` to push all of the branches to this remote.

Comment: this didn't work. So here was my workflow. 1) Make a new repo called `railsguides-blog`. Make a new rails project in local folder, run `git init`, in terminal - `git add -A', 'git commit -m "first commit"', `git remote add upstream git@github.com:maxpleaner/railsguides-blog.git`, then `git push upstream --all`. I get `ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: Wow, so I figured it out, but it wasn't that hard ........ it was this command `git remote add origin https://github.com/MaxPleaner/railsguides-blog.git` and then `git push -u origin master` --- worked fine. I got that code from the page that appears on github right after making a new repo.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was on the page that comes up right after making a new repo on github. It provides the code right there. Specifically, after running `git commit` it is instructed to run `git remote add origin https://github.com/MaxPleaner/railsguides-blog.git` and then `git push upstream --all`. Easy.